# PHP PDO How to create a parameterized UPDATE function

Tags: php, pdo

I have a parameterized INSERT function and would like to do the same for an UPDATE but can't quite get the implementation correct.

My INSERT function:

```
    $bind = ':'.implode(',:', array_keys($data));
    $sql  = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . implode(',', array_keys($data)) . ') ' . 'VALUES (' .$bind. ')';
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array_combine(explode(',',$bind), array_values($data)));
```

In my UPDATE function I will be passing 3 parameters, the table_name, key_value_data_array[] and row_id.  The key/value array is in the format column_name => data

Answer (score 0):

When I update something in a database I use this code, should work fine:

```
 $update_query = $database_connection->prepare("UPDATE table SET column = :value");
 $update_query->execute(array(':value'   => $some_value));
```